# misplaced constructs in constructor

Tags: java

why these errors ? I placed them in the comments...
eclipse is giving me these errors and I still can't figure why...even talking about a boolean and I see none...someone shed some light please..

```
public class GameInit 
{
 private static  int   playerNo;
// ArrayList<Integer> players = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
 Map <Integer, String> player = new HashMap<Integer, String>();


 public GameInit()
 {
  int firsthalf;
  int secondhalf;    
  firsthalf = playerNo/2;
  secondhalf = playerNo - (playerNo/2);

 for(int i = 0; i < firsthalf; i++)
 {
    player.put<i, "Human">; //syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens??? 
 }

 for(int j = firsthalf; j < secondhalf; j++)//syntak error on tokens,  misplaced construct(s) ????
 {
     player.put<j, "Alien">;//error: multiple markers at this line:cannot convert from bool to String? ehhrrrmm...where is the boolean??? 
 }


 }
```

Comment: What do you think `<>` are for? Why do you think so?

Comment: Hint: you're trying to call a method (`put`). How do you normally call a method? What kind of brackets do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are trying to access to your method `put` and you are using 2 parameters so you have to change `<>` for `()`. From this:

```
player.put<i, "Human">;
```

to this:

```
player.put(i, "Human");
```

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Comment: am bowing my head down in shame!!! How the f**K did i miss that...haha
sorry guys for wasting your time and mine too! damn!!!

Comment: Don't worry ;) and please mark it as accepted answer if your issue have been corrected. Thank you! :D

Comment: @JessicaFede In the left of the answer you have a "tick" to accept the answer (if the answer solved your problem). The arrows are for upvote or downvote the answer (if you are agree with it or not) Thank you again! ;)